# I am trying to create web part with 4 images when moved on to image hover text on the image and when clicked goes to destination url

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, web-part, jquery

[image: expected view]

how can we create a above kind of webpart when moved on the image it should hover some text and when clicked it should go to destination URL.I created a tiles list and trying to link it in a webpart but its not working.Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: You can add images with links directly into your page using the editing tools in the ribbon, no need for a web part or anything fancy.

Comment: Thank you. But how can i get hover text on the images can we hover text directly from editing tools?

Comment: Pure CSS photo tiles: http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/